# Combining two reclassified raster images in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have two images one is a subset of the other and have reclassified both images in arcmap.

The subset has been reclassified to assign zero value to the pixels while the main image has been reclassified to various pixel values, however the area of the subset within the main image is wrongly classified.

To address this problem I want to merge the two reclassified images so the subset area is assigned zero pixel value in the final output.

I have tried various tools in arcmap including combine, raster calculator, and merge but both give outputs which excludes areas outside the subset.

How do i combine these two images so the final output contains both the reclassified subset and the main image?

Comment: Have you tried using a conditional statement in the raster calculator as indicated here (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87670/reclassifying-only-part-of-raster-keeping-rest-unchanged?rq=1) and making sure processing extent (in "Environments") are set are set to Union?