# Clipping shapefile to interpolated surface (contours) in R?

Tags: r, interpolation, clip

R novice here, trying to work through the ever-daunting task of clipping my data. I've posted several questions regarding how to clip various types of data, so here we go with another, complete with all of my data to reproduce results. :)

Data:
[CSV data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/90cs2vk4shhhc3w/TZ_ReturnPeriods.csv?dl=0), 
[Shapefile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a950o87dxkmzo4b/TZA_adm0.csv?dl=0)

My map is of rainfall return periods in Tanzania. I used the IDW interpolation method to achieve this plot. Instead of having the entire surface over/around TZ contoured, I only need the contours to be clipped to the TZ shapefile. Here's my code, which was provided by [this excellent tutorial](http://www.geo.ut.ee/aasa/LOOM02331/R_idw_interpolation.html):

```
setwd("D:/Mapping-R/Returns-Practice")

library(ggplot2)
library(gstat)
library(sp)
library(maptools)

tz <- read.csv("TZ_ReturnPeriods.csv", header = TRUE)

temp <- tz
temp$x <- temp$Lon
temp$y <- temp$Lat

coordinates(temp) <- ~x + y

plot(temp)

x.range <- as.numeric(c(28.61, 41.19))
y.range <- as.numeric(c(-12.61, -0.19))

tz.grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1],
                               to = x.range[2],
                               by = 0.1),
                       y = seq(from = y.range[1],
                               to = y.range[2],
                               by = 0.1))
coordinates(tz.grid) <- ~x + y  

plot(tz.grid, cex = 1.5, col = "grey")
points(temp, pch = 16, col = "blue", cex = 0.5)

idw <- idw(formula = Return.10 ~ 1,
           locations = temp,
           newdata = tz.grid) 
idw.output <- as.data.frame(idw)
names(idw.output)[1:3] <- c("Longitude", "Latitude", "Return")  

ggplot() + geom_tile(data = idw.output,
                     aes(x = Longitude,
                         y = Latitude,
                         fill = Return)) + 
  geom_point(data = tz, 
             aes(x = Lon, y = Lat),
             shape = 21, 
             color = "red")

tz.contour <- readShapePoly("TZA_adm0.shp")
tz.contour <- fortify(tz.contour, region = "NAME_0")

ggplot() + geom_tile(data = idw.output, 
                     alpha = 0.8,
                     aes(x = Longitude,
                         y = Latitude,
                         fill = round(Return, 0))) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "cyan", high = "orange") +
  geom_path(data = tz.contour, aes(long, lat, group = group), color = "grey") +
  geom_point(data = tz, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat), shape = 16, cex = 0.5, color = "red") + 
  labs(fill = "Rainfall", title = "10 Year Return Period in Tanzania")
```

This code produces this image: [image]

BUT that was only half of the battle. I need to clip the Tanzania shapefile to the contoured surface so that ONLY the contours within Tanzania's borders are shown. I've found many almost-solutions, but nothing that quite works.

Comment: Possible duplicate question - please check this [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61243/clipping-a-raster-in-r) (and specifically the answer using the `raster` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the raster package to clip.

In your code, starting from the line `tz.contour <- readShapePoly...` do the following:

```
tz.contour <- readShapePoly("TZA_adm0.shp") # use this to clip
tz.contour.dfr <- fortify(tz.contour, region = "NAME_0") # use this to plot

library(raster)
idw.r <- rasterFromXYZ(idw.output[, c("Longitude", "Latitude", "Return")])
idw.crp <- crop(idw.r, tz.contour)
idw.msk <- mask(idw.crp, tz.contour)
idw.msk.dfr <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(idw.msk))
names(idw.msk.dfr)[1:2] <- c("Longitude", "Latitude") 

# now plot:
ggplot() + geom_tile(data = idw.msk.dfr, 
                 alpha = 0.8,
                 aes(x = Longitude,
                     y = Latitude,
                     fill = round(Return, 0))) + 
   scale_fill_gradient(low = "cyan", high = "orange") +
   geom_path(data = tz.contour.dfr, aes(long, lat, group = group), color = "grey") +
   geom_point(data = tz, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat), shape = 16, cex = 0.5, color = "red") + 
   labs(fill = "Rainfall", title = "10 Year Return Period in Tanzania") +
   coord_equal() +
   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
         panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting errors at the idw.crp stage and onward. "Error in .local(x, y, ...) : Cannot get an Extent object from argument y." I didn't change anything in my code so it's interesting that we're getting different results. :( Any insight?

Comment: Yes. You need to make sure you clip with the SpatialPolygon, not the data frame. I have extended my code to make that clear.

Comment: thank you so much! Sorry about uploading the csv--my mistake! Is there any way to also get rid of the grid behind the country borders? Not a big deal if not.

Comment: Try `?theme`.  I updated the example.