# Load images into a multi-band raster in R?

Tags: r, clip

I have a Landsat image with 11 bands. I need to run k means classification in R. But I do not need the whole of the image as my study area is much smaller. So I have created shapefile of the Region of Interest (ROI) in ArcGIS which specifically covers my study area.

How does one clip a raster image to the extent of a shapefile (here my ROI) in R?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please refine your post into a single, focused question. It would also be helpful to include any code you have created.

Comment: with the mask function, check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61243/clipping-a-raster-in-r

Comment: If you do not have an irregular area you can use raster::crop along with raster::extent to define the bounding box. This is much faster than raster::mask and would look something like: crop(x, extent(-160, 10, 30, 60) )  The arguments for raster::extent are: xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax defining the corners of the bounding extent.